# Suggestion: merge tags "remote" and "telecommute"

Tags: discussion, retag-request

They refer to the same topic. I suggested this in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) and @MattGiltaji pointed me here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have merged them and created a synonym (from "remote" to "telecommute").

Comment: Great, thanks :)