# Please merge the telecommute and remote-work tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Seven years ago, [the remote and telecommute tags were merged](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3036/suggestion-merge-tags-remote-and-telecommute). The tag [remotework](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remotework) is also a synonym of [telecommute](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telecommute).

We currently have a separate [remote-work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-work) tag. Please merge this tag as well.

Comment: I see they are already synonyms... https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/remote-work/synonyms

Comment: @DarkCygnus I'm only seeing "remotework" as a synonym for "remote-work". Under [synonyms for telecommute](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/telecommute/synonyms) I see "remote" and "work-from-home" but not "remote-work". Neither telecommute nor remote-work appear in the synonym lists for each other.